# What is the RSS feed link for the newest WordPress plugins?

Tags: plugins, rss, wordpress.org

Is there an RSS feed for the page that displays the newest WordPress plugins from the official plugins repository?

I know of the following link, but I'm looking for an RSS feed that I can add to my reader.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/browse/new/

Answer (score 0):

This page has a link to its feed in its header. If you are using a browser that has implemented [auto-discovery](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-autodiscovery) already, you get an icon for that in the address bar.

The URL is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rss/browse/new/

Answer (score 0):

You can try these RSS feeds:

Latest plugin updates.

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/rss/
```

Most popular:

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/rss/browse/popular/
```

Newest:

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/rss/browse/new/
```